# C++ Linux: Process PID from its path

Tags: c++, linux, process, path, pid

I'm searching a way to get the current PID of a process having its path.

For example I know that the path `firefox` is `/usr/bin/firefox`, I have launched it and I would like to find its PID in C++.

How could I do that ?

Comment: /proc/<process id>/exe is a link to the binary.  You could go through each process id and search for ones where the link is pointing to the executable you are interested in.

Comment: Note that firefox and multiple other Linux/Unix commands allow several invocations, so searching for the executables path may render several results, and you may not isolate the one you're actually after.

Comment: @VaughnCato sorry it's the opposite that I need.

Comment: Either way, you can get corresponding paths and process ids, so you can either find all the process ids that have a given path or the path for a process id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the 'pgrep' program. Source is here, I think: http://procps.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thank you very much I will check that one!

Comment: I have an issue on linking step. I'm trying to use the method `get_proc_stats` (to do another step using the library instead of my own code) but I go the following error: "undefined reference to \`get_proc_stats'". I'm compiling with "pkg-config --cflags --libs libprocps". Other methods like `openproc` or `closeproc` I have no problem.

Comment: I have pushed in a git repo an example that fail when linking: https://github.com/zedtux/test_libprocps

Comment: I followed what @BraveNewCurrency tell and now it's working: I'm using `openproc()` and `readproc()` methods in order to get an instance of `proc_t` per tasks and then compare the `cmd` field with the process name so that I can get the `tgid` from the `proc_t` instance.